# Cache npm install Task in VSTS

Tags: npm, build, azure-devops

I have configured a private agent in VSTS and have installed NPM there globally. When I'm trying to install NPM through my build task, it is still installing NPM packages for every build which is taking an aweful lot of time- approximately  12 minutes.

How can I cache the NPM installations so that the build time is reduced?

Answer (score 5):

We use [npm-cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache), npm-cache is a node module that will calculate a hash of your package.json file for every hash it will create zip folder on your build server with the content of node_modules, now npm install is reduced to extracting a zip on every build (of course only in case you didn’t actually change package.json).

The idea is: in the first time the tool download the npm packages and save them locally, in the second time if the `package.json` not changed he takes the packages from the local disk and copy them to the build agent folder, only if the `package.json` changed he downloads the packages from the internet.

1. Install the npm-cache on the build machine:

   `npm install npm-cache -g`
2. In the build definition add Command Line task (Tool: `C:\Windows\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm-cache` (or just `npm-cache` if you add the tool to environment path variables); Arguments:`install npm`; Working folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` (or where `package.json` located).

Answer (score 4):

MS has finally implemented this feature (currently in beta) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/caching/index?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm

From there:

```
variables:
  npm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm

steps:
- task: CacheBeta@0
  inputs:
    key: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/package-lock.json
    path: $(npm_config_cache)
  displayName: Cache npm

- script: npm ci
```

Comment: Have you verified this works? I was trying the same approach, but after reviewing build logs, the `npm ci` command is still executed and it simply overwrites the existing cached content. I.E. I am not seeing any time saving with this approach.

Comment: further testing- it's solely caching the `.npm` directory, which is the npm cache. so this saves a very small amount of time (based on my test project). however, it DOES run the command `npm ci` on all runs. In order to avoid executing a script you need to use the CacheBeta input `cacheHitVar` then add a `condition` to the script task.

Comment: @jrap I've tested this, yes. And I also didn't see any noticable performance improvement. At least because it also takes (almost the same) time to download the cache from the MS server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot cache the NPM installations as no such a built-in feature for now.

However there's already a user voice submitted to suggest the feature : [Improve hosted build agent performance with build caches](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32044321-improve-hosted-build-agent-performance-with-build), and seems the VSTS team are actively working on this now...

For now, you can try to [speed Up NPM INSTALL on Visual Studio Team Services](https://akj.io/speed-up-npm-install-on-vsts/)

Answer (score 0):

[Use Cache task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops)

> Caching is added to a pipeline using the Cache pipeline task. This
> task works like any other task and is added to the steps section of a
> job

With the following configuration:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:    
    key: 'YOUR_WEB_DIR/package.json'
    path: 'YOUR_WEB_DIR/node_modules/'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: 'YOUR_WEB_DIR/frontend'
```

You can use key `YOUR_WEB_DIR/package-lock.json` too, but be aware that file might be changed by other next step like `npm install` so hash also will be changed.